# Python - Change button state based on multiple widgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-button

I am trying to change the state of a button based on the user input of two other widgets contained in my program. Ideally I would like the button to change state any time one/both of the widgets values is missing and only be enabled when both values are present. I'm unsure of how to go about doing this. I have tried writing a function to check the value of the two widgets control variables and configure the button accordingly, but with no luck. If any other information is needed for clarity/context, please let me know. Thank you in advance.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

results = dict()  # holds control vars
categories = ['a', 'b', 'c']  # options for combobox


def change_state():

    c = results['category'].get()
    n = results['number_of_recipes'].get()

    if c and n != 0:
        button.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)

    else:
        button.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)


root = tk.Tk()

results['category'] = tk.StringVar()

ttk.Combobox(
    root,
    textvariable=results['category'],
    values=categories,
    justify='right'
).grid(
    column=0,
    row=0
)

results['number_of_recipes'] = tk.IntVar()

ttk.Spinbox(
    root,
    textvariable=results['number_of_recipes'],
    from_=1, to=20, increment=1,
    justify='right',
).grid(
    column=1,
    row=0
)

button = ttk.Button(
    root,
    text='Button',
    state=tk.DISABLED
)

change_state()

button.grid(
    column=2,
    row=0
)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"I have tried writing a function to check the value of the two widgets control variables and configure the button accordingly, but with no luck. "_ - what does "no luck" mean? What you describe is how you do it: create a function that checks the control variables and configures the button.

Comment: What do you expect `c and n != 0` to do? Are you trying to check that `c` isn't zero and `n` isn't zero? Or, are you trying to check that `c` is any non-false value and `n` is not 0?

Comment: I was trying to check that c had some value to it at all since it is a StringVar and that n is not 0. What I meant by "no luck" was that what I tried did not have the desired outcome. I understand that a function was needed, I was just writing it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `trace` method for the `StringVar` and `IntVar`, and bind it to the `change_state` function.

Then the `change_state` function will execute whenever either of the widgets values changes and it can set the button to be enabled or disabled accordingly.

For example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

results = dict()  # holds control vars
categories = ['a', 'b', 'c']  # options for combobox

def change_state(*_):  # <--- now accepts *args
    c = results['category'].get()
    n = results['number_of_recipes'].get()

    if c and n != 0:
        button.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)

    else:
        button.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)

root = tk.Tk()

results['category'] = tk.StringVar()
results['category'].trace('w', change_state)  # <---- added this


ttk.Combobox(
    root,
    textvariable=results['category'],
    values=categories,
    justify='right',
).grid(
    column=0,
    row=0
)

results['number_of_recipes'] = tk.IntVar()
results['number_of_recipes'].trace('w', change_state)  # <-- added this

ttk.Spinbox(
    root,
    textvariable=results['number_of_recipes'],
    from_=1, to=20, increment=1,
    justify='right',
).grid(
    column=1,
    row=0
)

button = ttk.Button(
    root,
    text='Button',
    state=tk.DISABLED
)
button.grid(
    column=2,
    row=0
)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you. What is the purpose of the *_ parameter?

Comment: It's required by the trace method... When it calls the callback it calls it with an argument. @david